# Terms showing up in object cache on unrelated pages

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, performance

This is perplexing. I'm running Debug Bar on my dev site. I noticed today that the object cache reporting shows memory taken up by terms I've created using register_taxonomy when not on pages associated with that custom content type. I wouldn't think this was a huge issue except I also use outside plugins that create content types and taxonomies, and these don't show up in the object cache on unrelated pages.

I'm hooking these registrations to init. Which I assume is the correct route.

Just trying to do some performance tweaks. This is making me nuts. Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Taxonomies gets registered on`init` on **every** page load. That is how WordPress intended it to be, and there is no workaround to this unfortunately. Anyways, if you are not registering a huge amount of taxonomies (*and custom post types for that matter*), you should not be running into issues